# OpenCSV CSVWriter file shows different separator when using broker pipe (¦) unicode character.

Tags: opencsv

I was using OpenCSV API to create CSV with separator as broken pipe(¦). when i ran this piece of code it works fine in eclipse. whereas if i create runnable jar of the same, broken pipe shows replaced with another unicode character.

Note: i don't want to use {,;|} as delimter.

CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(
                        new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(:c:\csv\test.csv"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)),
                        separator,
                        CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER);

i tried with different writer with and without charset option but no luck.
 Any guess what could be missing?

Comment: Which tool are you using to view the files in both scenarios. Try opening the csv files in textpad, notepad applications to view raw data.

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, i am using notepad++ tool to view generated CSV. but tool is not an issue. end goal is i am using generated CSV to load into SQLServer using BulkCSVReader(Microsoft JDBC driver API). so at the of reading CSV using JDBC API, i am specifying same broken pipe as delimter.but it says column mismatch and reason because of broken pipe stored/displayed differently.